# How to stop Chrome from telling websites to render in dark mode?

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I'm trying to get a new Windows 10 laptop setup.

I've installed Chrome, of course, and I'm finding that in it most webpages render in dark mode.

For example, superuser.com is rendering in dark mode.

What I've done:

- In the Windows 10 Settings app, there's this:

  Settings => Personalization => Colors => Choose your color

I have that set to "Light". Though I have tried setting that to "Custom" and then setting both "Choose your default Windows mode" and "Choose your default app mode" to "Light" and it made no difference.

- In chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark, and that I've Disabled.

But I'm still seeing the contents of pages displayed in dark mode.

- When I go to https://www.google.com/, and click on the "Settings" link at the bottom, it displays a popup that includes "Appearance: Light". If I click on it, it brings me to a preferencees page: https://www.google.com/preferences#appearance that allows me to "Turn Dark theme on or off."  I've tried setting it to "Light theme" and to "Device default" and regardless, I'm still seeing web pages rendering in dark mode.

What gives?

Where else is this set?

How do I find it?

Comment: I would see if you can reset colour and themes to default, save, restart and test.  I do not use any dark mode and Chrome and Chromium Edge do not (ever) render in dark mode.

Comment: I've tried all of that. I've even tried running chrome from the command-line with --disableFeatures=DarkMode.

Comment: I will look around but cannot promise much. 2 Windows 10 and 1 Windows 11 prerelease machines here with no dark mode and browsers do not show dark mode at all.

Comment: I'm going to try reinstalling Chrome.

Comment: Do you have dark mode set in Windows?

Comment: As I said in my original post, I have Windows set to light.